# Why do OpenGL-based VTK targets in drake executed via `bazel test` sometimes fail on Linux?

Tags: linux, opengl, vtk, drake

While a binary works with `bazel run`, when I run a test using `bazel test`, such as:

```
$ bazel test //systems/sensors:rgbd_camera_test
```

I encounter a slew of errors from VTK / OpenGL:

```
ERROR: In /vtk/Rendering/OpenGL2/vtkXOpenGLRenderWindow.cxx, line 820
vtkXOpenGLRenderWindow (0x55880715b760): failed to create offscreen window

ERROR: In /vtk/Rendering/OpenGL2/vtkOpenGLRenderWindow.cxx, line 816
vtkXOpenGLRenderWindow (0x55880715b760): GLEW could not be initialized.

ERROR: In /vtk/Rendering/OpenGL2/vtkShaderProgram.cxx, line 453
vtkShaderProgram (0x5588071d5aa0): Shader object was not initialized, cannot attach it.

ERROR: In /vtk/Rendering/OpenGL2/vtkOpenGLRenderWindow.cxx, line 1858
vtkXOpenGLRenderWindow (0x55880715b760): Hardware does not support the number of textures defined.
```

May I ask why this happens?

(Note: This post is a means to migrate from http://drake.mit.edu/faq.html to StackOverflow for user-based questions.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best workaround at the moment is to first mark the test as as `local` in the `BUILD.bazel` file, either with `local = 1`, or `tags = [.., "local"]`. Doing so will make the specific target run without sandboxing, such that it has an environment similar to that of `bazel run`.

As an example, in `systems/sensors/BUILD.bazel`:

```
drake_cc_googletest(
    name = "rgbd_camera_test",
    # ...
    local = 1,
    # ...
)
```

If this does not work, then try running the test in Bazel without sandboxing:

```
$ bazel test --spawn_strategy=standalone //systems/sensors:rgbd_camera_test
```

Please note that you can possibly add `--spawn_strategy=standalone` to your `~/.bazelrc`, but be aware that this means your development testing environment may deviate even more from other developer's testing environments.